# Verify uniqueness of a pair in both directions: either A-B or B-A to add into container

Tags: c#, .net, unique, tuples

I'm building a graph and verify uniqueness of a vertex to add using `HashSet<T>`. Its method Add() returns true if an item was not added already.

What technique can I use for edges? I need to verify that either pair A-B or pair B-A pair were added once.

Here's a lightweight version of the data I'm using:

```
interface INode
{
    INode[] Previous { get; }

    Node Next { get; }
}
```

Then I have:

```
INode current;
INode[] allPrevious = ExternalMethod1(current);
INode[] allNext = ExternalMethod2(current);
```

So I can't build a graph while go round recursively, I have all the data stored up to iterate over.

Comment: Can you provide more information on that graph please. strategy will probably depend on that graph.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` orderable? If so, the obvious is to always put the "lesser" item first.

Comment: @Damien: Elaborate, please. Also take a look at the details in updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own equality comparer implementation for edges and set [`HashSet<T>.Comparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346458.aspx) to an instance of it. For example:

```
class Edge
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
}

class EdgeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Edge>
{
    public bool Equals(Edge lhs, Edge rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.From.Equals(rhs.From) && lhs.To.Equals(rhs.To)) ||
               (lhs.From.Equals(rhs.To) && lhs.To.Equals(rhs.From));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Edge e)
    {
        return e.From.GetHashCode() ^ e.To.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Of course you would also have to check for nullity. All the [standard caveats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) apply to the `GetHashCode` implementation as well.